# Sending html array to a PHP form

Tags: php

This is my actual code. I am trying to send the array "sku" which has copied the original array of "parent..." to php with $_post. But no matter what I try it won't send.

```
<script>
var sku = new Array();
for (q=1;q<parent.item_num;q++)
{
sku[q] = parent.itemlist[q].code;
}

</script>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please show some of your HTML. The post form would be a good place to start. Also, if you have tried anything, show us what you've tried (or at least describe a bit).

Comment: it should be like this `$my_array = $_POST['item']`

Comment: I understand that, but my problem is my array has no name identifier to transfer the information via post.

Answer (score 1):

If the name attribute is something like `name="item[]"`, then `$_POST['item']` is an array, so you can use foreach loop to go through all items.

Answer (score 1):

If your form method is `post` you can use `<?php $_POST['item'] ?>` to access the array.

You can also use `foreach` to loop through all of the items:

```
<?php 
  foreach($_POST['item'] as $item){
     ... do something with $item ...
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in HTML, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="arr[]" id="arr1" />
<input type="text" name="arr[]" id="arr2" />
```

simply create arrays under their normal `$_GET`/`$_POST` variables, so, `var_dump($_REQUEST['arr'])` would yield:

```
arr => array(
    [0] => "whatever was in arr1", 
    [1] => "whatever was in arr2"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will help :

```
$id = 4;
if (isset($_POST['item_'.$id]))
{
    item[$id] = $_POST['item_'.$id];
} else {
    item[$id] = 0;
}
```

PS : slugonamission way seems more appropriate

Comment: yeah sorry, I mixed 2 things.